# Why am I getting "rvm: command not found" on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, ruby, rvm

I am trying to set up Siri Proxy, and I come up to the steps:

```
rvmsudo rvm install 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
rvmsudo gem install eventmachine CFPropertyList httparty json uuidtools
```

But I can't do them due to these errors:

```
rvm: command not found
rvmsudo: command not found
```

I know this is due to Ruby Version Manager not being installed or properly set up. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and I only have SSH access.

This is what I've done beforehand to install and initialize Ruby:

```
sudo apt-get install nano ruby build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion
bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: when you run `bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)` it shows you where it is installed, you need to replace `$HOME/.rvm` with the installation path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the commands `rvm` and `rvmsudo` are not in your `PATH`.  The `PATH` is a variable that lists all of the directories that are searched for commands.

You need to find out where the `rvm` and `rvmsudo` commands are actually located; it could be in `/usr/local` somewhere or in `/opt`. If the RVM software was installed in `/usr/local` I would guess that it would work just fine; check `/opt`.

Then add the directories that contain commands to your `PATH` (on the command line and in `.profile`):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/rvm/bin:/opt/rvm/sbin
```

(The directories are just examples.) Using `$PATH` preserves your current PATH and adds the two new directories on the end.  Directories are searched from left to right and are separated by `:`.

More on this can be found in `man bash` or `man sh` or `man ksh` depending on your shell.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu you need to use ~/.bashrc instead of ~/.bash_profile in case if per user installations, So do:

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bashrc
```

or if you're using ubuntu 12.04:

```
echo '[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bashrc
```

and after that:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and test with:

```
type rvm | head -1
```

you should get: rvm is a function

Answer (score 0):

The latest installation needs the users to be added to the Group `rvm` and then need to login again.

Please note that closing the terminal and reopening is not enough; the user has to logout and log back to take the Group addition in effect.

Adding the user to the Group can be done by:

```
sudo usermod -a -G rvm <user>
```

The binaries can also be at different locations based on the method you followed during the installation.
I had them at `/usr/share/rvm/`

You can also look at `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`

Then you add this line to the end of `~/.bashrc`

```
[[ -s /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

**Note:** If you are using a shell other than `bash` you may need to add the path accordingly.

For instance, if you using `zsh` shell add the above lines to the `~/.zshrc` file.